# Javascript - Why does this if statement print "Hello" twice in the console?

Tags: javascript

For this sample code, it prints "Hello" twice into the console:

```js
var x = 10;

if ( (null) || (console.log("Hello")) || x > 5 ) {

  console.log("Hello");

}
```

I assume when the "if" statement is read, it reads the console.log, then prints it, and since x > 5, the return statement is true, then consoles the second "Hello".

Can someone tell me if this is correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your function:

1. Sets variable and it's value `var x = 10`
2. Checks the conditions, until one of them "is" `true` (returns
   `true`)
3. `(null)` returns itself, so the functions checks other condition
4. `(console.log("Hello"))` returns nothing (`null`), so the function
   checks other condition
5. `x > 5` returns `true`, so the execution of code inside `if{ < code > }` happens
6. `(console.log("Hello"))` inside `if{ }` executes.

As you can see, the `(console.log("Hello"))` is executed both, while checking conditions inside `if` statement and while executing "the insides" of that `if`. That's why you see "Hello" logged 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

console.log has a return type of undefined.

You're seeing the console.log output twice, because you've called it twice:

Once in your if condition, and the next in your if statement.

Your if statement will run because you're using OR, and x = 10 > 5

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement first encounters `null`, which is false, then does a `console.log()`, which returns `undefined` so is also false, and finally `x > 5`, which is true. Thus the `if` statement is true, and it goes into the body and does another print.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume when the "if" statement is read, it reads the console.log, then prints it, and since x > 5, the return statement is true, then consoles the second "Hello".

More accurately, the "if" statement is **executed**. Specifically, the condition is evaluated. Since `null` is "falsey", the right of the `||` operator is evaluated. Which executes the first `console.log()`. This in turn returns `undefined` which is also "falsey" and the next operand of the next `||` is evaluated. `x>5` evaluates to `true`, so the second `console.log()` is executed.

Note that this is not a very good way to write code. `console.log()` shouldn't be used inside an `if` condition like this. It's return value is meaningless since it always returns `undefined`.

Comment: To further clarify, the first & second condition statements will always execute, because even if the operator was an &&, it requires validation from at least two conditions.

Comment: @alex067 That isn't quite correct: if it's a `&&` and the LHS is false, the interpreter will short circuit and skip the RHS (no need to evaluate as the whole will be false anyway).

Comment: @Klaycon oh yes that is true, sorry wasn't thinking straight

Comment: @alex067 In the case of `||`, if the first operand evaluates to `true`, then the remaining operands would not be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

The first console.log you wrote is in the if statement, that function will be called when the if statement is evaluated. The second statement will be called if the condition in the if statement is met. The console.log itself returns undefined and has no real purpose to be in your if statement. I would recommend removing it as I don't believe it is achieving what you intended
Good luck :)